# VBS - Remove part of string after last "/"

Tags: vbscript, character

This is what I have:

```
Dim pathBefore
pathBefore = "product/subproduct/item/item"
```

This is what I need to get from pathBefore:

```
Dim pathAfter
pathAfter = "product/subproduct/item"
```

What I can do to achieve this?
I have tried with RegEx but it is not acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2):

@Gurman:

```
>> s = "product/subproduct/item/item"
>> a = Split(s, "/")
>> ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) - 1)
>> WScript.Echo Join(a, "/")
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetParentFolderName(s)
>> WScript.Echo Left(s, InstrRev(s, "/") - 1)
>>
product/subproduct/item
product/subproduct/item
product/subproduct/item
```

Comment: They surely are better. Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Dim pathBefore, pathAfter, temp, i
pathBefore = "product/subproduct/item/item"
temp = Split(pathBefore,"/")
For i=0 To UBound(temp)-1
    pathAfter = pathAfter & temp(i) & "/"
Next
pathAfter = Left(pathAfter,Len(pathAfter)-1)
MsgBox pathAfter
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Don't, there are better (more efficient/easier on the eyes) alternatives.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Will be happy to learn from them. This was the first way that came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Find the last `/` then read upto that point - 1

```
pathAfter = left$(pathBefore, instrrev(pathBefore, "/") - 1)
```

Comment: The $ is an invalid antiquity.